# How to append to a list of object in c# using WPF binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Model:

```
public class Team
{
    public string KnownName { get; set; }     //player known name
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }      //player position
    public string Number { get; set; }    
}
```

WPF:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dtHomeSquad">
    <WrapPanel  >
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPath" Text="{Binding Path = Number, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPath2" Text="{Binding Path = KnownName, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbxInMatch" Click="AddOrRemoveFromMatch"IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}" />
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="LstHomeSquadNames" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="423" Margin="4,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="231"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="12"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource dtHomeSquad}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

C#:

```
private void AddOrRemoveFromMatch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newlist = new List<Team>();

    foreach (var player in HomePlayersList)
    {      
        if(player.IsActive)
            newlist.Add(player);
    }
}
```

OnLoad I have binded a list of objects to my list box using item source. I have a checkbox in the list box item when I check the checkbox I would like to append to the new list of an object if I uncheck if remove that object from the new list if it does not exist.

Is there a way of Appending the new object or remove using a unique value instead of creating a new list each time for eg if I had to select an item by index I would use the index of the Listbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. It notifies view if collection is changed. The base you need to know that binding uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces for notification and updating view.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ObservableCollection<Team>` instead of a `List<Team>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have Added INotifyPropertyChanged as @Connnell.O'Donnell and @DdarkSideE... worked as expected.

Model:

```
public class Team : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string KnownName { get; set; }     //player known name
    public string Number { get; set; }    
    public bool isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return IsActive; }
        set
        {
            if (value != isActive)
            {
                isActive = value;
                if(isActive)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsActive", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsActive", false);
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName, bool state)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    if(state)
    {
        WindowType1.HomeTeam.Add(this);
    }
    else
    {
        WindowType1.HomeTeam.Remove(WindowType1.HomeTeam.Where(i => i.Number == this.Number).Single());
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: You should accept one of their answers in that case.